# Why am I prompted to reinstall Wordpress every time I add a child theme?

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I'm using MAMP to serve up my local wordpress files. I've set up the database, updated the wp-config-sample.php file with my database-name, username, password, and tables. I've also changed the authentication key/salts.

I installed WP for the first-time and was able to access wp-admin dashboard with localhost.

When I went in and added a new child-theme directory in the themes folder, I am now prompted to reinstall wordpress which results in a database error.

Any insight as to why this is happening? The idea is to simply create a child theme- not sure why it's prompting me to reinstall WP.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like this is happening because of wp-config-sample.php remove it and install wordpress. It will generate  wp-config automatically

Comment: Hi- I just noticed that when I created the new theme-child directory, a new wp-config.php file was generated. I deleted the wp-config-sample.php, but I'm still prompted to reinstall wordpress (which leads to a database error). what do you recommend? thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be updating your wp-config.php (though it's usually auto generated) rather than config-sample?

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Comment: I downloaded the latest wp which only comes with wp-config-sample (did not see the wp-config.php). I'm using the standard 2017, just trying to create a child theme of 2017

Comment: everything works fine when I download WP, set up my DB and add the DB user/log in info in wp-config-sample. But the problems start when I add a new folder in the themes directory. 

The autogenerated wp-config has the same log-in/DB table prefix info as the old wp-config-sample that I deleted.

Comment: updated my typo (it said 2016, meant to type 2017)

Comment: Auto generate wp-config is right do not touch it.  When you creare a folder does it give you the issue or you are doing any code or moving the files in the directory on that time you are getting issue?

Comment: I get the issue once the wp-config is created. 

When I ran localhost and accessed wp-admin for the first time, I noticed that a new wp-config file was generated. I deleted the wp-config-sample file and went ahead with the new WP installation. That's when I got the database error. 
The wp-config populated the same values as the sample file.

Comment: UPDATE- i seemed to fix it when I went into the autogenerated wp-config.php and changed the $table_prefix  to a different value. That created 2 copies of the database tables. 
I manually deleted the first database-tables in mysql. Not sure if this is a best-practice or why this had to be done manually. 
Was this the correct approach?